# How can I change the file name of a downloaded csv file?

Tags: jquery, csv

I am using the script below to generate a csv download from a particular table.

I need to be able to change the name of the file downloaded so that it adds the current days date, and the name of the table it downloaded it from. Currently it just calls the csv file export.csv

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {    
        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td');

                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

            // Data URI
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        $(this)
            .attr({
            'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
        });
    }

    // This must be a hyperlink
    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

        // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
    });
});
```

Comment: Just change the second parameter value ... ?

Comment: Which one do you mean? The part at the end where it gives the filename export.csv? I'm not to sure what to change it to. Thanks

Comment: Answer added with full explanation for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the name of the table using `attr()`:

```
var tableName = $('#dvData > table').attr('name');
```

You can format the current date to a useable string for the filename like this:

```
function padZeroes(value, length) {
    var zeroes = new Array(length).join('0');
    return (zeroes + value).substr(-length);
}

var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear().toString();
var month = padZeroes(today.getMonth() + 1, 2);
var day = padZeroes(today.getDay(), 2);
var hours = padZeroes(today.getHours(), 2);
var minutes = padZeroes(today.getMinutes(), 2);
```

Putting it all together in the `click` handler:

```
$(".export").on('click', function (event) {
    var $table = $('#dvData > table');
    var tableName = $table.attr('name');

    function padZeroes(value, length) {
        var zeroes = new Array(length).join('0');
        return (zeroes + value).substr(-length);
    }

    var today = new Date();
    var year = today.getFullYear().toString();
    var month = padZeroes(today.getMonth() + 1, 2);
    var day = padZeroes(today.getDay(), 2);
    var hours = padZeroes(today.getHours(), 2);
    var minutes = padZeroes(today.getMinutes(), 2);
    var filename = tableName + '_' + year + month + day + '_' + hours + minutes;   

    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [ $('#dvData > table'), filename ]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried using that code but for some reason the filename is coming out as "undefined_20150701_1440" it seems to have the time right, but the date doesn't seem to make sense and the table name is not being generated, Any ideas? Thank you